# iOS app crashes when resuming from background

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout

I'm working on native iOS app using `UICollectionView` with custom `UICollectionViewLayout`. App crashes when resuming after in `background` for a period of time and I got crash logs:

```
    Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
    Thread 0 Crashed:
    0   libswiftCore.dylib      0x00000001005425dc 0x100404000 + 1304028
    1   MyAppName               0x000000010015e148 0x1000f4000 + 434504
    2   MyAppName               0x0000000100178284 0x1000f4000 + 541316
    3   MyAppName               0x00000001001172e0 0x1000f4000 + 144096
    4   MyAppName               0x0000000100158ef8 0x1000f4000 + 413432
    5   MyAppName               0x000000010011e5bc 0x1000f4000 + 173500
    6   UIKit                   0x000000018820b5b4 +[UIView(Animation) performWithoutAnimation:] + 80
    7   MyAppName               0x00000001001556dc 0x1000f4000 + 399068
    8   MyAppName               0x00000001001558ec 0x1000f4000 + 399596
    9   UIKit                   0x0000000188a3f3a8 -[UICollectionView _createPreparedCellForItemAtIndexPath:withLayoutAttributes:applyAttributes:isFocused:] + 432
    10  UIKit                   0x0000000188261adc -[UICollectionView _updateVisibleCellsNow:] + 4628
    11  UIKit                   0x000000018825c808 -[UICollectionView layoutSubviews] + 228
    12  UIKit                   0x00000001881f81e4 -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 656
    13  QuartzCore              0x0000000185b8a994 -[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 148
    14  QuartzCore              0x0000000185b855d0 CA::Layer::layout_if_needed(CA::Transaction*) + 292
    15  QuartzCore              0x0000000185b85490 CA::Layer::layout_and_display_if_needed(CA::Transaction*) + 32
    16  QuartzCore              0x0000000185b84ac0 CA::Context::commit_transaction(CA::Transaction*) + 252
    17  QuartzCore              0x0000000185b84820 CA::Transaction::commit() + 500
    18  QuartzCore              0x0000000185bd8190 CA::Display::DisplayLink::dispatch_items(unsigned long long, unsigned long long, unsigned long long) + 592
    19  IOKit                   0x0000000183315e54 IODispatchCalloutFromCFMessage + 372
    20  CoreFoundation          0x000000018303d030 __CFMachPortPerform + 180
    21  CoreFoundation          0x00000001830557d4 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 56
    22  CoreFoundation          0x0000000183054f0c __CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 436
    23  CoreFoundation          0x0000000183052c64 __CFRunLoopRun + 1800
    24  CoreFoundation          0x0000000182f7cc50 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 384
    25  GraphicsServices        0x0000000184864088 GSEventRunModal + 180
    26  UIKit                   0x0000000188266088 UIApplicationMain + 204
    27  MyAppName               0x0000000100129f5c 0x1000f4000 + 221020
    28  libdyld.dylib           0x0000000182b1a8b8 start + 4
```

How to solve or debug this problem?

This is how to initialize UICollectionView and register Cell:

```
    collectionView = {
        let collectionView = UICollectionView(frame: CGRectZero, collectionViewLayout: layout)
        collectionView.dataSource = self
        collectionView.delegate = self
        collectionView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = false
        collectionView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = false
        collectionView.registerClass(MyCollectionCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: MyCollectionCell.reuse)
        collectionView.registerClass(MyCollectionHeaderCell.self, forSupplementaryViewOfKind: MyCollectionHeaderCell.kind, withReuseIdentifier: MyCollectionHeaderCell.reuse)
        return collectionView
        }()
```

Comment: Could you provide your code where you init your collectionView and register your collectionViewCell. The logs says that the problem somewhere with it

Answer (score 0):

You Can Check the which place to crashes the app.
to be following this steps.
I think it's helpful.

First You select the **Show the Breakpoint Navigator.**

and add the **Add Exception Breakpoint**

[image]

Then Enter the Keyboard Key.

[image]

After the Run the Application and check the which place to crashes your app.